# Not the address I want content?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm just getting more and more confused by wasting more time on my code. I just want the content of the iterator, not its address. Here is my code:

```
Peptides tempPep;
tempPep.set_PEPTIDE("AABF");
std::vector<Peptides>::iterator itPep = std::find_if (this->get_PepList().begin(), this->get_PepList().end(),boost::bind(&Peptides::Peptide_comparison, _1,tempPep)); 
if (itPep != this->get_PepList().end()) 
{

   Spectra tempSp;
   tempSp.set_Charge(1127);
   tempSp.set_Snum(1);
   std::cout << "without iterator "<< this->get_PepList()[0].get_New_S_num() << std::endl; 
   // output -> 0
   std::cout << "with iterator" << itPep->get_New_S_num() <<std::endl;
   //output -> 1129859637
}
```

Comment: What does `get_PepList()` return a copy or reference? `itPep` is probably dangling as the vector returned from the call has expired.

Comment: In C++ types are paramount. What is `Peptides` and what is the type of `this` and how does `get_PepList()` and `get_New_S_num()` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
std::vector<Peptides> p = this->get_PepList();
std::vector<Peptides>::iterator itPep = std::find_if (p.begin(),
    p.end(),boost::bind(&Peptides::Peptide_comparison, _1,tempPep));
```

Comment: Thank you! could you describe it a bit more please!?

Comment: @khikho: The lifetime of the vector returned from `this->get_PepList()` expires at the end of the line to the call to `std::find_if` since you call it like `this->get_PepList().begin()`. This means `itPep` was holding an iterator into a vector that no longer existed. To ensure the vector remains valid, I changed the code to copy the vector returned from `get_PepList()` into a variable, i.e. `std::vector<Peptides> p = this->get_PepList();`. This ensures the vector is still around when you access one of its elements with the `itPep` iterator.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content, point to it: `*itPep`

An iterator overloads the `*` operator and returns the data. (thanks for the correction, I did not know that!)

Comment: `itPep` is not the address directly. An iterator overloads the `*` operator and returns the data from there.

Comment: Also, you can surround a snippet of text with \`\` to get it to display like code. ;p (I'll edit this for you)